# How come my second, delayed CSS animation is messing up everything?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm just animating a simple text, then, after some time, I want it to disappear, however, a few issues appear:

1. When it first **fades in**, you can see that the opacity value isn't respected at all, the text appears almost out of nowhere.
2. When it **fades out**, you can see that the movement is weird and the opacity transition runs *after* the movement.

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

#message {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 60px;
  left: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  animation: showMessage 1.5s ease 1.5s forwards, hideMessage 1.5s ease 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes showMessage {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 100;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes hideMessage {
    0% {
        opacity: 100;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="message">
    Hey, look at me!
  </div>
</div>
```

What gives? If I remove the second animation, everything comes back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `opacity` goes from 0 to 1, so the change is happening almost instantly. About the weird movement when leaving, seems fine to me.

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

#message {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 60px;
  left: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  animation: showMessage 1.5s ease 1.5s forwards, hideMessage 1.5s ease 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes showMessage {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes hideMessage {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="message">
    Hey, look at me!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, I hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 960px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #message {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            color: black;
            font-size: 18px;
            opacity: 0;
            top: 60px;
            left: 100px;
            transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
            animation-name: showMessage;
            animation-duration: 3s;
            animation-delay: 500ms;
            animation-direction: alternate;
        }

        @keyframes showMessage {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate3d(0, -55px, 0);
            }

            50% {
                opacity: 100;
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
            100%{
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate3d(-65px, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        @keyframes hideMessage {
            0% {
                opacity: 100;
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate3d(-65px, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="message">
        Hey, look at me!
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```